# Date object not catching comparisons in google scripts (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script that is comparing two dates against each other.  But both are coming in differently.  one I converted to a string format Mo/day/year then to a date format.  The other is taken directly for a google spreadsheet cell already in date format.  But when I run a comparison on them, it doesn't work even if the date falls within the comparison range.  Here's my code:

```
 function formatDate(someDate){
  var x = someDate.split("T");
  var v = x[0].split("-");
  var newDate = new Date();
  newDate.setFullYear(v[0],(v[1]-1),v[2]);
  //var newDate = v[1]+"/"+ v[2]+"/"+v[0];

  return newDate;
  }

 //calling formatDate within another function
 if(startDate != ''){
    if(singleCard[j].date != undefined){
      var k = singleCard[j].date;
      var f = formatDate(k);
      var dt = new Date(f);

 if(dt >= startDate && dt <= endDate){  //date comparison
   //do something here
 }
```

The start/end dates is coming in a format of:

```
    Fri Oct 12 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

The singleCard[j].date is coming in as a string:

```
    "2012-10-12T16:57:51.517Z"
```

and then I use:

```
   var f = formatDate(date) -> var dt = new Date(f)
```

to process it.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the exact content of the `singleCard[j]`? Splitting dates with `T` seems suspicious to me.

Comment: Sure it's:  "2012-10-12T16:57:51.517Z"

Comment: Have you checked that `startDate` and `endDate` really are `Date` objects, and not strings?

Answer (score 0):

When you do

`var newDate = v[1]+"/"+ v[2]+"/"+v[0];`

are you sure you used *year / month / day*  in the right order ?

Did you try to log the result of `var dt = new Date(f);` to see its value as a date object ?

*sorry if my questions seem obvious but since I don't know your local settings for date I can't be sure how you handle that.( I'm in a country where we use dd/mm/yyyy so I'm used to have problems with that ;)*

**EDIT** : just saw your comment... shouldn't it be `v[0]+"/"+ v[1]+"/"+v[2]` (yyyy/mm/dd)

***EDIT 2*** : I think you have to give hh mm ss parameters as well when you use setFullYear();

something like

```
 newDate.setFullYear(v[0],(v[1]-1),v[2],0,0,0,0);
```

in order to get it working. It is also necessary (I'd even say mandatory) to set hh mm ss and mSec to 0 since you are using a `<=` and `>=` comparison, Equality will probably never be true if you let hours , minutes , seconds and milliseconds free to live their own life.

Don't forget date objects are ALWAYS complete dates with time, even when you don't show / use them.

Comment: I changed the date function to the edit in the original code above.

After I run it through formatDate() as I have it above I get back a date object:

"Fri Oct 12 2012 09:57:51 GMT-0700 (PDT)"  like this.

Comment: Actually both modes seems to be supported. `new Date('2012/1/2') == new Date('1/2/2012')`

Comment: deleted my comment since you changed your question while I was writing ;)  see edit2

Comment: I added the hours, mins etc as you suggested.  I get:

     Fri Oct 12 2012 09:57:51 GMT-0700 (PDT)

     Fri Oct 05 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
for dt (after formatDate) and startDate respectively but when it goes to a comparison dt > startDate it still is not comparing properly it immediately breaks out of the if statement.

Comment: Not sure I get it clearly ... startdate = oct 12, dt = oct 5 right ? ...then indeed dt is not > startdate... and what is enddate ?

Comment: sorry startdate is Oct 5, dt is Oct 12, endDate is Oct 12.

Comment: why has dt 09:57:51 as time value if you tell me you set hh:mm:ss to 0 ? (sorry I didn't see the "respectively" in the former comment)

Comment: If I use your values the result is logical since enddate is at 0 hour mm ss and dt at 09 hours so dt > enddate.

Comment: Alright all my date objects are exactly the same.  So if my start date is:
      Sat Sep 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) 
And my end date is:
     Wed Oct 31 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT) 
And the date I'm checking against the start and end is: 
      Fri Oct 12 2012 17:22:18 GMT-0700 (PDT) 

So at my conditional it's not picking it up.  
      if(dt >= startDate && dt <= endDate)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17962/discussion-between-verber-and-serge-insas)